# How to disable error messages in production laravel api

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, exception

I am building api in laravel and I am catching exceptions if they occur and I am returning them as response. The problem is that I only want to show them in my dev enviroment. Setting `APP_DEBUG=false` doesn't solve the problem, error message is still in response.

```
  public function foo()
  {
       try{
           $this->bar();
       }catch(\Exception $e){
           return $this->error($e->getMessage(),'Something went wrong', 403);
       }
  }
```

This returns json for example:

```
{
    "error": "No query results for model [App\\Models\\User].",
    "message": "Something went wrong" 
}
```

I want to have this in my dev enviroment, but on production I would like to have only the message like:

```
    {
    "error": "500 Server Error",
    "message": "Something went wrong" 
    }
```

How do I achieve this and is this a good practice to do? I haven't found any solution yet, except to overwrite message if `APP_ENV=production`, but I have a feeling that there is a better way to do this.

```
   protected function error($error, $message = '', $code = 400)
    {

        $this->response['error'] = $error;
        
        $this->response['message'] = $message;

        if(env('APP_ENV') === 'production'){
            $this->response['message'] = '500 Server Error'
        }

        return response()->json($this->response, $code);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch it inside `App\Exceptions\Handler`

Use the render function to intercept all exceptions with json as response (for api only)

And within add check which env is it currently being deployed.
This is the only way to make sure your error overwrite will work only in production.

Also use `config(app.env) === production` is best practice instead of using env.

Now you can throw any kind (custom) exceptions , and all can be "filtered" by this code.

Extra note about config as best place as pointed out by @dbf (thanks mate)

- This is based on how mr Otwell himself use config() instead of env(), in core and all of his laravel related oackages
- dont forget also that config is cached, meaning faster in load time compare to raw env,
- have a look at this link https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-get-data-from-the-env-file-directly ... As one of many recommended way to use config() instead of env()

Comment: Why is using `config('app.env')` instead of `.env` best practice? Where is your source of information? `env.environment` Is dominant across configs, so where does it get this information concerning its environment?

Comment: Thanks for asking... This is based on how mr Otwell himself use config instead of env, dont forget also that config is cached, means faster load time, als last you can find this almost everywhere recommended, one of the is here https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-get-data-from-the-env-file-directly... I apologize if this is not according to one standard ... Sometimes something easy and direct is not always the laravel way

Comment: I know, my comment is meant in such a way to suggest to put references in your answer not just explain it with best practice :)

Comment: Ok @dbf thank you for your input and advice .. was not really clear from your 1st comment ..  have a fun day

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @dummy.learn's answer, the best way to handle exception is inside `App\Exceptions\Handler`, laravel's all exception will pass through `App\Exceptions\Handler` before it render or report, even those you didn't catched.

You can handle exception like this:

```php
$this->renderable(function (Throwable $e, $request) {
        return new ExceptionResource($e);
});
```

ExceptionResource is an API resources from `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource` which you can see document from here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources.

And I prefer to check enviroment from app helper not env or config instead, the helper will return a bool, that I think readability is better.

Example in ExceptionResource, showing error if environment is local dev or unit test:

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    if(app()->environment(['local', 'testing']))
        $error = $this->resource->getMessage();
    else
        $error = 'Server Error';

    return [
        'error' => $error,
        'message' => 'Something went wrong'
    ];
}
```